# Why Arima.sim return the error message for non-stationary AR model?

Tags: r, arima

When I simulate an Ar model with Arima.sim in R, it returned an error message.

"Error in arima.sim... 'ar' part of model is not stationary"

For example:

```
set.seed(1)
ar = arima.sim(n = 400, list(ar = c(2)), sd = 1)

Error in arima.sim(n = 400, list(ar = c(2)), sd = 1) : 
  'ar' part of model is not stationary
```

I checked online and there's indication saying that arima.sim can not handle non stationary model, or some seasonal model. Why it failed? Does it has anything to do with the algorithms that was used to generate random numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AR(1) model with i.i.d. errors is stationary if the autoregressive parameter r satisfies |r|<1. Hence, you are indeed trying to simulate a nonstationary case. It makes *almost* complete sense then that we get an error.

The only nonstationary case where I'd expect to see no errors is |r|=1, i.e., the unit root case. Then we get something like

[image]

where the errors are standard normal. Now the values aren't small, but also not infite.

Then when |r|>1, we have an explosive case. And yes, in that case algorithms also start to matter: since, when simulating AR(1), we want the realization to look realistic, we have a burn-in period where, say, the first 5000 observations are discarded. In your case, the algorithm may generate 5000+400 observations and show you only the last 400 (in a stationary case). The issue is that, as I said, the values become useless very fast once |r|>1. For instance,

```
x <- numeric(50)
x[1] <- rnorm(1)
for(i in 2:length(x))
  x[i] <- 2 * x[i - 1] + rnorm(1)
x
#  [1] -1.274118e+00 -2.920323e+00 -2.690751e+00 -5.066151e+00 -1.169234e+01 -2.409816e+01
#  [7] -4.787102e+01 -9.502020e+01 -1.912421e+02 -3.823547e+02 -7.653762e+02 -1.530197e+03
# [13] -3.060378e+03 -6.121630e+03 -1.224165e+04 -2.448105e+04 -4.896242e+04 -9.792375e+04
# [19] -1.958463e+05 -3.916917e+05 -7.833816e+05 -1.566764e+06 -3.133528e+06 -6.267057e+06
# [25] -1.253411e+07 -2.506823e+07 -5.013646e+07 -1.002729e+08 -2.005458e+08 -4.010917e+08
# [31] -8.021833e+08 -1.604367e+09 -3.208733e+09 -6.417467e+09 -1.283493e+10 -2.566987e+10
# [37] -5.133973e+10 -1.026795e+11 -2.053589e+11 -4.107179e+11 -8.214357e+11 -1.642871e+12
# [43] -3.285743e+12 -6.571486e+12 -1.314297e+13 -2.628594e+13 -5.257189e+13 -1.051438e+14
# [49] -2.102875e+14 -4.205751e+14
```

Now imagine simulating 5000 observations for a burn-in and then providing the following 400. Thus, cases when |r|>1 are actually pointless to simulate. One exception would be if you assume that X<sub>0</sub>=c for some fixed constant c and want to simulate only a few periods; in that case you could use something similar to my loop above.